# Obtaining all values from a built form

Tags: forms, 8

I'm building a form and setting values via

```
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('My\Module', ['key1' => 'x']);
```

where I set the passed `key1` as the default values for the associated fields : in `My\Module\buildForm`, you would find

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $presets = array()) {

    $form['key1'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => isset($presets['key1']) ? $presets['key1'] : $query->get('key1')
    ];

    return $form;
}
```

This takes place in a controller not directly related to the form and I'd like to retrieve all values set, either as defaults or as parameters of the page, something like `['key1' => 'x']` if no parameter is passed to the page or `['key1' => 'v1']` if the page is called with `?key1=v1`

How can I get all the values on my form array (besides filtering on the field names)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you put the preset values in the default values of form elements. They are at this point only in `$form`.

The values in `$form_state` are filled after the form is submitted, as a result of a GET/POST request.

But then your code, that calls the formBuilder, has no longer control. This will be handled by the submit method you have defined for the form.

Comment: `FormState` is  mostly there to illustrate what I am looking for, I don't really need it.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but you mean that there's no helper/method to extract the values of the form? Basically, I'm looking for a way to modify the form values in my controller and get the resulting values.

Comment: Can you put an example in your question, what is in $presets, where this is put in $form and what you want to extract?

Comment: Sure, I hope it's clearer

Comment: There is no helper method. `#default_value` is used to render the form in html. The processing of values only takes place after submit.